# how to remove windows service entry manually

Tags: c#, wcf

I was trying to implement wcf service and host it on windows service. At that time I was able to install and uninstall wcf service using **installutil.exe** command. By mistake I have deleted project and my test wcf service was installed in computer. Now I want to remove that service manually. Any Idea?

When I tries to delete using **Installutil.exe /u path** it throws and exception

```
Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'XXX' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I Have copied path from my service **properties -> path to executable** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
sc delete "servicename"
```

in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to a command window and type:

```
     {your service name} /uninstall.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path seems to be incorrect hence this command fails: InstallUtil.exe /U YourService.exe

try the below command
sc delete "yourservice"